# Creating a GUI with Glade and Webassembly

Tags: c++, glade, webassembly

The Glade software is a visual editor for GUI development. The output is a XML file which can be used in a C++ application for user interaction. A normal C++ program is compiled to run on a desktop, for example in Fedora Linux. In contrast, the Webassembly standard has the aim to execute programs inside the browser. Webassembly is a “C++ to Javascript” converter with a high performance.

My question is: Can i use the Glade GUI creator tool for building a webassembly app which can run inside the webbrowser? The reason is, that I'm not interested in creating native Linux apps, but platform independent apps which can be run in any browser no matter if it's Linux, WIndows or Mac.